# Format Long Form Date and Time in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, format

I have a dataframe with the first column that has date and time as "2016-03-01 23:50:00" format. When I do `dput(ordereddata$Date_Time)` the output is

```
> dput(ordereddata$Date_Time)
structure(1:2, .Label = c("2016-03-01 00:10:00", "2016-03-01 00:20:00"
), class = "factor")
```

I would like to format this column so it stores the date and time into `MM-DD-YYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM`

I have anytime and lubridate libraries, but am still unable to convert the format. I tried a few commands and none are getting stored. It is unable to parse. Any ideas?

Comment: Just `as.POSIXct(x)` will do it.  Vectors are converted to character implicitly.

Comment: So, I tired this: as.character(x). This produces x as class character. I then tried as.Data(x, "%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s"). This produces NA still. Recall my original x is "2016-03-01 00:10:00", "2016-03-01 00:20:00". I dont understand why it still stores it as NA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- structure(1:2,.Label=c("2016-03-01 00:10:00","2016-03-01 00:20:00"),class="factor")

x <- as.POSIXct(x)
```

Comment: After I changed the class from factor to POSIXct. I then used the format function: format(x, "%m/%d/%Y %h:%m:%s")
[1] "03/01/2016 Mar:03:1456812600" "03/01/2016 Mar:03:1456813200"                 The output after the date is all weird and i do not understand my mistake?

Comment: You need a capital letter for the HMS portion, like this: format(x, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"). If these two have answered your questions, please select this as a solution, so that the community knows and people can find the answer even faster in the future.